# How to return a string from a function in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of delimited values that I want to show the user such as:

```
[delimCC] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3;
        [1] => 4;
        [2] => 5;
    )
```

WHat I need, is: 3;4;5 (a string). How can I take the output of this array and make it a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
implode(';', $delimCC);
```